# How to crop car number on this pic given its relative bbox coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, data-science, scikit-image

I have this pic:
[image: pic_to_be_cropped]

I have the following relative coordinates:

```
[[0.6625, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6035714285714285]]
```

(however I don't understand, why are here 5 values instead of usual 4 and what they mean)

My attempt with `scikit-image` that shows whole pic instead of cropping:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, draw

img = io.imread(pic)

vals = [[0.6625, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6035714285714285]]

vertices = np.asarray(test_vals)

rows, cols = draw.polygon(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1])

crop = img.copy()

crop[:, :, -1] = 0
crop[rows, cols, -1] = 255

io.imshow(crop)
io.show()

# shows whole pic instead of cropping
```

My attempt with `opencv` gives errors because coordinates are in float format:

```
import cv2 as cv


vals = [[0.6625, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6035714285714285]]

x = vals[0][0]
y = vals[0][1]
width = vals[1][0] - x
height = vals[2][1] - y

img = cv.imread(pic)

crop_img = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
cv.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv.waitKey(0)

#  TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How to crop car number on this pic given its relative bbox coordinates?

I am not limited to any framework, so if you think that TF or anything else might help - please suggest.

Comment: "however I don't understand <...> what they mean" - this is the actual problem. You must find out what these numbers mean first.

Comment: these numbers are sets of coordinates that mark the corners of a rectangle. the first and the last set are the same. I don't know what you generated these numbers with, so I cannot account for why there is the double entry.

Comment: @warped yeah, I also noticed that the last entry always repeats first. I am given these coords and have to crop car number using em (my ultimate goal here is to get the car numbers as integers from the pics)

Comment: @warped I was wondering maybe some of the modern ML frameworks uses this kind of format when cropping/rectangularing/bboxing

Comment: Have you tried just multiplying the floats by the relevant image dimensions and marking those? It might be a means of avoiding resizing issues. Just add the multiplication in to your opencv code and crop, see if it’s in the right ball park. In the first instance, you could use opencv just to draw lines between the points on an image Mat where you have the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspection of

```
vals = [[0.6625, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6035714285714285], [0.7224999999999999, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6571428571428571], [0.6625, 0.6035714285714285]]
```

shows that the first and the last entry in the list are identical. 
In image processing, the position (0,0) is the top left corner. Looking at the values in the list, you can assume that the coordinates are given as follows:

```
[top_left, bottom_left, bottom_right, top_right, top_left]
```

The fact that all numbers are between zero and 1 suggests that these are relative coordinates. To rescale back to image dimensions, they need to be multiplied by height and width, respectively:

```
# dummy img sizes:
image_height = 480
image_width = 640

# rescale to img dimensions, and convert to int, to allow slicing:
bbox_coordinates = [[int(a[0]*image_height), int(a[1]* image_width)] for a in vals]
```

now, you can use array slicing on the image to crop:

```
top_left = bbox_coordinates[0]
bottom_right = boox_coordinates[2]

bbox = img[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0], top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]]
```